# Android - Statistics on OS Versions

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have to know how many users are currently using my mobile app(production) in Android OS 4.1 and 4.2

how can i know from google play console.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the breakdown of users of your app by android version in the Statistics tab in the play developer console. On that page, scroll down below the graph to see how many users are on each version.

These statistics won't differentiate between build variants, but if you discount the number of developers/testers who are using your non-production variants, you can get a good idea of the production usage on different versions.
[image: Play Console Statistics Tab]
[image: Play Console Statistics Installs on Active Devices]

Comment: How do i discount no of developers/testers which i used in beta testing